# Why doesn't Subject emit new value to the component after being called from Effect in Angular?

Tags: angular, effect, subject

I am attempting to achieve a communication channel between a service file (where the Subject lives), a component file (which subscribes to that Subject) and an effect file (which calls the service file to update Subject).

[Figure 1 - The problem described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05b5H.png)

The problem is that when I subscribe to the Subject from the service file, I expect to get the newest value which was sent from the Effect file, but as Figure 1 shows, I struggle to receive that value in the component.

Component file:

```
this.subscription$ = this.service.getValue().subscribe(( value: boolean ) => {
  console.log("value received: ", value);
})

// ...

public onClickAction(): void { this.service.execute(...parameters) }
```

Service file:

```
private subject$: Subject<boolean>;

constructor() { this.subject$ = new Subject() }

// ...

public setValue(value: boolean): void { this.subject.next(value) }

// ...

public getValue(): Observable<boolean> { return this.subject$ }

// ...

public execute(...parameters): void { this.store.dispatch(action) }
```

Effect file

```
action$ = createEffect(() => { 

//...

this.service.setValue(true)

})
```

Could someone please explain to me why I am not getting any updates from the Subject? Alternative solution is to register the Subject in the effect file, but that does not look right to me plus I really wish to understand why this is not working.

Thank you very much!

Edited: I have replicated this problem on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-82bscp?file=src/app/services/service.service.ts) and it is working there. I have still no idea why it was not working on our project, maybe there is something I don't consider when working with effects.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem and share it via Github or JS Fiddle or Stackblitz or any other similar service?

Comment: This is a company project, so I wouldn't like to share much more of the codebase :/

Comment: You don't need to share the full code base. Replicate only the problem you are facing with dummy data and share it.

Comment: Hi Shravan, I am sorry about the late reply. I have edited the original post with the link pointing to the StackBlitz project.

Comment: Check where you are injecting the Service in your project. In the stackblitz example, you have provided it in root. Are you doing the same in your main project as well?

Comment: The service is injected in App module and I am sure that is working correctly. There might be something wrong with the Subject? Or maybe it could be that the service is initialised multiple times somehow and the subject doesn't emit the next value, because at the time, it is not initialised yet? Just some thoughts...